# Implemet an dinamic array ( I have access to positions that can't exist)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, new-operator

For some reason my implementation allows 0 size array access to 0 position and 5 size array access 50 position. While both positions must get me an segmentation fault error for my perspective. I think that maybe it can be caused by allocate memory wrongly but by my side it looks right ,someone can tell me why I obtain that result.

My code for array:

```
class vector{
 private:
  int length;
  int cap;
  T* arr;
 public:

  vector(int n){
   arr = new T[n];
   length = n;
   cap = n;
  }

  vector():vector(0){};

  vector(vector<T> & other){
   arr = new T[other.size()];
   length = other.size();
   cap = other.capacity();
  }
  ~vector(){
   delete[] arr;
  }

  T& operator[](int ind) {
   return arr[ind];
  }

  const T& operator[](int ind) const{
   return arr[ind];
    }
};
```

My test:

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
  vector<int> v;
  v[0] = 5;
  vector<int> v2(5);

  std::cout<<v2[50]<<" "<<v[0]<<std::endl;
 }
```

Output:

```
  0 0
```

Comment: "...both positions must get me an segmentation fault error for my perspective" - your perspective seems to carry *definition of behavior*, something you're code is lacking. Thus the nature of invoking *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What's the difference between `length` and `cap`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard says it's an *undefined behavior*, not a *segmentation fault*.

This works just because `(arr + 50)` is a memory position reserved for your program.

Also remember that positions always exist (ok, if you are not at the last byte of your RAM): at the physical level they are just bits, so there is always something there.

If you try accessing for example v[12345678] this will probably result in a segmentation fault though.

Anyway this in an *undefined behavior*, so **NEVER** rely on these effects.

Comment: them I must check limits and throw a exception?

Comment: @warwcat Not necessarily, `std::vector` provides two methods for index accessing, `std::vector::at` and `std::vector::operator[]`, the former uses bound-checking and throws `std::out_of_range` if index is out of bounds whilst the latter does not do any bound checks (UB if index out of bounds) - this is a good approach and typical of STL containers.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking your function's parameters.

What you should be doing is something like

```
T& operator[](int ind) {
    if(ind >= 0 && ind < length)
        return arr[ind];
    else
        throw(std::out_of_range("vector"));
}
```